# Guidelines - extension methods vs partial class

Tags: c#, extension-methods, partial-classes

We are debating at work the best way to define methods for an entity class - as extensions methods or using partial classes. The kind of methods we're talking about don't modify the state of the entity, they are purely "helper" methods that interrogate the state and return a value.

The main benefit to both approaches is to keep the entity class clean, while still providing intellisense support to client code.

I don't have a strong preference either way but am curious to know if others have a preference (or know of documented guidelines) towards one or the other.

I started writing the list of merits for each approach that I could think of, but in the end all I've come up with is:

**Partial Classes**

- The method definition resides within the class (even if it's another file) so Visual Studio tool support for "find method" (e.g. ALT-\ in resharper) will locate the method
- The existence of the other file containing helper methods is obvious as soon as the entity class is opened due to use of the partial keyword

**Extension Methods**

- The naming of the file ("entityNameExtension") and its whereabouts in the project (in an "Extensions" sub-folder) are intuitive and easy to search for

Can anyone else add their opinion to this?

PS I don't feel this is a duplicate of the following question, as the asker of that question was content to mark a response which outlined the functional differences as the correct answer, which doesn't answer the question about which approach is best practice in this scenario:
[Partial Class vs Extension Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017673/partial-class-vs-extension-method)

**EDIT - I'm seeking people's preference towards one approach or the other, as there are no documented guidelines that we can find for this particular scenario. Both approaches are possible and neither violates any design principles, so it is a matter of preference and I'd like to know yours.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, extension methods are good for two things. First, when you apply them to interfaces, it gives you the illusion of writing an abstract base class that lets you define some common methods, but it's more flexible because a class can only have one base class but can implement multiple interfaces. Second, if you apply it to regular classes, then I tend to look at it as some kind of hacking. When the original class lacks some methods, and you really feel like they should have those methods, but they don't, and they are out of your reach, so you are forced to implement them somewhere else, as utility methods, and it gives you an illusion that it's actually there.

Both cases are syntactic sugar only in the end, but extending interfaces makes much more sense to me, if I just look at LINQ's Enumerable class for example. I've used those extension methods on dozens of completely different classes, so it really paid off. An example of a class extension method is when I made my own string.IsNullOrWhitespace before it was added to the framework.

Extending an interface seems right because the interface defines a contract, and you can rely on that contract in your extension method, but when you extend a regular class, it may change and break your extension method. Of course, interfaces may change, too, but they tend to be more thoroughly designed I think, but I don't have any statistics.

Then there's the case of object-oriented programming. Where do you feel like your method should go, who uses those additional methods, where are the boundaries. If you think a method belongs inside a class, then put it in the class. It makes sense, it's simple. People wrote really good classes before extension methods were invented, they put everything where it belonged and life was good, haha.

Partial classes are cool because they are not that big of a hack as extension methods. They are not syntactic sugar, not magic. It is merely the best and easiest way to deal with auto-generated classes, so I don't think too much of it. I've written some code generators, and they emit regions where humans can write their own stuff and it is not overwritten in subsequent code generations. It is more comfortable that way, but that's all. I can't change how .NET tools generate code, and they don't do it this way, so partial classes are the next best thing.

To sum it up, my opinion is to only use extension methods when you really have to, and go with partial classes whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you would create a partial class uless your original class has grown out of its purpose. Take a look at your classes you would like to extend, are they really doing one thing, or are they doing many things. Take a look at at the Single Responsibility Principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

If you can create methods that OTHER CLASSES can take advantage of, I would recommend creating an extension class. It will extend the capability of other classes, making your toolbox more flexible.

Comment: Hi emedbo, as mentioned they are entity classes and the proposed methods are merely helpers to retrieve state. So there's no violation of the SRP. The methods are specific to this entity, so they can't be genericised for use with other classes.